# Is it possible to control the space between the body and :before and :after content?

Tags: css

I intend to add braces around inline-block divs:

```css
div.block {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.block:before {
  content: "(";
}
div.block:after {
  content: ")";
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span>2 days ago</span>
</div>
```

The problem: The newline and space between the the span and the :before and :after content is reduced to one space, although there must be no space.

I know that it is possible to fix the problem by destroying the readability with the following hack or by writing everything in one line:

```css
div.block {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.block:before {
  content: "(";
}
div.block:after {
  content: ")";
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><span
  >2 days ago</span
></div>
<div class="block"><span>2 days ago</span></div>
```

This has the disadvantage, that I can not use any more any generic pretty printer to format the code.

So is there a CSS-way to control the space between the `:before` and `:after` content and the body of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add floats to the braces - [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/gabrielbran/pen/MYOJaJ)

For this to work, you need to have `display: inline-block` on all the elements inside the block `div` as well.

```css
div.block {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.block * {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.block:before {
  content: "(";
  float: left;
}
div.block:after {
  content: ")";
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span>2 days ago</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Defining the `:before` and `:after` as floats is tricky. Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: yes - far too many to mention. Floating 'pseudos' (or any element for that matter) IMHO is risky, and can be done better with positioning.

Comment: @jbutler483 in general I prefer prevention to inverting.

Comment: Killing all margins in the body seems to be a bit risky, but for my particular use case it might be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can put brackets to `span` directly.

```
div.block {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.block span:before {
  content: "(";
}
div.block span:after {
  content: ")";
}
```

Comment: Yes but the intention is to have more than one span in the block. So the parenthesis should be around the block.

Comment: @ceving: you can use one span as a wrapper, then `div.block > span:before/after`. Question is, why the parenthesis aren't in HTML directly.

Comment: The content is automatically generated: a brief summary of content possibly being hidden. If I can use CSS I do not need to code it in JavaScript. The braces are somehow markup. I could us also an italic font or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use positioning for this, allowing you to add the brackets correctly, so long as your parent is positioned `relatively`, and your `pseudos` are positioned `absolutely`.

You can then subsequently use the `top:`, `left:`, `right:` and `bottom:` declarations on the absolutely positioned child to position relative to the parents' position:

---

See below for a simple demo of this:

```css
div.block {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
div.block span:before {
  content: "(";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.4em;
}
div.block span:after {
  content: ")";
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.4em;
  top: 0;
}
.large {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span>2 days ago</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span>There was a question asked about</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span class="large">css</span>
</div>
```

---

**The REM Unit:**

> A relative unit, like em, but it is always relative to the "root"
>   element (i.e. :root {}) rather than using the cascade like em does.
>   This vastly simplifies working with relative units. ~[Css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/)

Comment: Would it make more sense to use EMs for the bracket positioning to make it relative to the font size?

Comment: @JohnReid: I was avoiding using 'fractions' of measurements, since a brackets' width is not equal to an 'M's width. But have edited.

Comment: So the `-0.4em` depends on the font the user has selected?

Comment: Darn those fractions! I guess that there will always be the issue of which type of font you're using and how much width the bracket should use. Coders beware!

Comment: @ceving: This would be suitable for *most* fonts, since the brackets are usually ~40% width of a **M** However, an alternative method, possibly more reliable, is to use [REM](http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/) units. The **-0.4em** should be good for the 'common' fonts at least.